# Select only numeric variables of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, predicate

I know that the question is very easy, but I have a more specific one:

I have a data frame, with 50 variables (numeric and non-numeric) and 5000 observations.

Now what I want to do is create another data frame containing only the numerica variables of the original one.

On this website I found the solution of my problem, that is:

```
numeric_variables<-unlist(lapply(original_data,is.numeric))
X<-original_data[numeric_variables]
```

But I was wondering: why if I try like this, it does not work instead? what's wrong?

```
numeric_variables2<-apply(original_data,2,is.numeric)
x<-original_data[numeric_variables2]
```

Comment: `apply` converts to `matrix` and matrix can have a single type so, it is essentially converting to character type if there are character columns.  Check `cbind(1:5, LETTERS[1:5])` with tidyverse, it is `original_data %>% select_if(is.numeric)` or `iris %>% select(where(is.numeric))`

Comment: Try `Filter(is.numeric, df1)`

Comment: even better would be `iris[mapply(is.numeric, iris)]` for example

Comment: @markus,doesnt work

Comment: Okay, re-closed, keeping Markus's dupe about how to select numeric column, but also adding a dupe that explains that `apply` converts things to a matrix, which loses class information. With akrun's comment, hopefully that's enough to steer anyone finding this question in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

#### try this :

```
names_num <- names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))
df_num <- df[, names_num]
```